# How to create folders dynamically using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Requirement: I am trying to create the BKP folder in 10 server using the below code but some how it is not creating the new folder in servers.

```
foreach ($instance in Get-Content "C:\servers\List.txt")
{
    $local = Get-Location;
    $final_local = "C:\BKP";

    if (!$local.Equals("C:\"))
    {
        cd "C:\";
        if ((Test-Path $final_local) -eq 0)
        {
            mkdir $final_local;
            cd $final_local;
        }

        ## if path already exists
        ## DB Connect
    }
}
```

Comment: mkdir for make new Folder?

Comment: Hi Arashzag , thanks for reply, Already I used mkdir in my code.can you try to share the code which can help me.

Comment: do you want to make new folder with $final_local path ?

Answer (score 2):

**First** : you are using the wrong test, you should use :

```
if($local.Path -eq "C:\")
```

*The equal method is there to compare objects* have a look to :

```
$local | get-member
$local | fl *
```

**Be careful PowerShell CmdLet return objects**.

**Second** : if `$local.Path` is equal to `"C:\"`, you create nothing.

---

Your code would look like :

```
ForEach ($instance in $(Get-Content "C:\servers\List.txt")) 
{ 
  $local = Get-Location;
  $final_local = "C:\BKP";

  if($local.Path -ne "C:\")
  {
    cd "C:\";
    if((Test-Path $final_local) -eq 0)
    {
      mkdir $final_local;
      cd $final_local;
    }

    ## if path already exists
    ## DB Connect
}
```

Comment: Its creating folder in Local instead of remote servers specified in the c:\server\list.txt

Comment: Your test is not the good one `.Equals` do not do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks JPBlanc for your reply. I didn't understand. Please change my code .

Comment: I do not try to understand the context, i just change your test (the if clause).

Comment: Still its creating in local computer only

Comment: @Franklin - you are looping over the contents of a serverlist but you are nowhere connecting to that server *(by share or remoting) to create the folder.

Answer (score 0):

use this command to create directory :

```
ForEach ($instance in Get-Content "C:\servers\List.txt") 

{ 
$local = Get-Location;
$final_local = "C:\BKP";

if(!$local.Equals("C:\"))
{
    cd "C:\";
    if((Test-Path $final_local) -eq 0)
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$final_local";
        cd $final_local;

    }

    ## if path already exists
    ## DB Connect

}

}
```

Comment: I didn't find any difference for the script I posted and the above code.

Comment: still I can see the folder is created in local only

Comment: Can some one help me on this Topic

Answer (score 0):

Try using the invoke-command i am assuming credentials are needed for the servers you can skip it if it works for you.

```
$credentials = Get-Credential

$create = { $local = Get-Location;
            $final_local = "C:\BKP"

             if(!$local.Equals("C:\")){
                cd "C:\";
                 if((Test-Path $final_local) -eq 0){
                      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$final_local";
                      cd $final_local;
               }
         ## if path already exists
           ## DB Connect
     }
 }
ForEach ($instance in Get-Content "C:\servers\List.txt")  {
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $create -ComputerName $instance -Credential $credentials
}
```

Comment: Thansk Ashu for your help but unfortunately it is not working.I mean its creating on local drive only.